# Compare string from input

Tags: c

I'm trying to ask the user for input, and I need to make it so that if the user types `exit`, it terminates the program.

Here's what I have, but it's not working for some reason:

```
int main(void) {
  char input[100];

  printf("Enter: ");

  while(fgets(input, 100, stdin)) {
    if(strcmp("exit", input) == 0) {
      exit(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Why is it not exiting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing everything *ALMOST* right.

The problem is that "fgets()" returns the trailing newline, and "enter\n" != "enter".

SUGGESTION:

Use [strncmp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncmp) instead:  `if (strncmp ("enter", input, 5) == 0) {...}`

Comment: Thanks, worked. Also, if the input required commas between values (for example, an input might be `test,15`), how would I separate those values and put them into other variables?

Answer (score 0):

Because input contains a trailing '\n'

```
  while(fgets(input, 100, stdin)) {
    char *p=strchr(input, '\n');
    if(p!=NULL){
        *p=0x0;
    ]
    if(strcmp("exit", input) == 0) {
      exit(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `scanf()`:

```
while(scanf("%s", input)) {
    printf("input : %s\n", input);
    if(strcmp("exit", input) == 0) {
        exit(0);
    }
}
```